# How to fix Java version mismatch on Mac?

Tags: java

I had Java 8 installed on my Mac and then found out that version 8 is too new for one of the tool I am using so I uninstalled Java 8 and was able to reinstall 7 update 67.

When I verify my Java version @ https://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp, I see that I have Java 7 update 67.  However, when I check my java and javac from the Terminal, I see that I have Java 8

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

~ $ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_20
```

Is there a way to get my java and javac version to 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and pop this in

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable on your mac to java 7. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/)

Answer (score 0):

In your .bash_profile, place the correct version of Java that you want to use - in this case, 7 - into your `$JAVA_HOME` bash variable.

The way to do this is through the use of the `libexec` tool provided with Mac.

```
export $JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
```